# ISC DHCP server web interface

Tags: dhcp-server, isc-dhcp, graphical-user-interface

I want to ask what web interface could be used for isc dhcp server on Ubuntu 22.04 server. I want to create dhcp server on ubuntu, I installed and configured isc dhcp but now i want to manage it from web ui(see statistics, clients, etc.). I found only this UI https://github.com/Akkadius/glass-isc-dhcp/. It looks like it is not maintained anymore(last commit 4 years ago) and have a lot of vulnerabilites. Are there any alternatives?

Comment: I know that it is not hard. But it is more user friendly to verify statistics, check leases or add new static ip via mobile phone using web page than ssh connection and vi/vim/.... Webmin looks good. I didn't know that and will test it for sure. Thanks for that.